# Textbox value compare before submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I want to let my two textboxes be checked before those get submitted. 
like

```
if textbox1 >= textbox2 submit
else show errorlabel and dont submit.
```

How can i do this?

Comment: How can I  show an error label at textbox if condition is false?

Comment: your tried code.... ?

Comment: From the SO Flagging section:   This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a *minimal example* in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide your onclick handler's implementation to extract the value of the two text boxes, then parse them as an int.

```
function submitForm() {
    var first = parseInt(document.getElementById("first"), 0);
    var second = parseInt(document.getElementById("second"), 0);

    if(first >= second) {
        // ...
        return true;
    } else {
        var hiddenTextBox = document.getElementById("error");
        hiddenTextBox.style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
}
```

This assumes you have two elements with `id="first"` and `id="second"` respectively, and a hidden element with `id="error"`

Comment: can i use for that ajax?and how to use it

Comment: @SANDEEP That depends on what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
$('#submitId').on('click',function(){
   if $('#textbox1').val() < $('#textbox2').val()){
      $('#erroLabel').show(); // showing error label
      return false; // to prevent submitting form
   }
});
```

Comment: OMG you used `jquery` tag in your `question`

Answer (score 0):

You can make function in javascript,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkValues()
        {
            var searchtext1 = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
            if(searchtext1=='')
            {
                alert('Enter any character');
                return false;
            }
            var searchtext2 = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
            if(searchtext2=='')
            {
                alert('Enter any character');
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and then in html form

```
    <form  method='GET' onSubmit="return checkValues();">
        <input type="text" id= "textbox1" name="textbox1" class='textbox' >
        <input type="text" id= "textbox2" name="textbox2" class='textbox' >
        <input type="submit" id='submit' value="Search" class ='button' >
    </form>
```